# Prove that $ {|\int_{\gamma} e^{iz^2} dz | \leq \frac{\pi(e-1)}{4e}}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis

Prove that

> $$ \large{\left|\int_{\gamma} e^{iz^2} dz\right | \leq \frac{\pi(e-1)}{4e}}$$

where $\gamma(t)=e^{it}, t\in[0,\frac{\pi}{4}]$

Since  $|e^{iz^2}|=e^{-2xy}$ now  $x=\cos(t),y=\sin(t)$

This mean $-1 \leq-2xy \leq0$ which imply maximum value of $|e^{iz^2}|=1$

And hence  $$ \left|\int_{\gamma} e^{iz^2} dz \right| \leq  \frac{\pi}{4}$$

but this is not what we are supposed to prove. what is missing here. Any hint.

Thank you

Comment: Just a side note: you want to use \left| and \right| to get $\left|\int_\gamma e^{iz^2}dz\right|$ (instead of just using |) to make it look neater

Comment: @Jack is this wrong problem ?